# How can I define Buttons and TextViews in static main or after that?

Tags: java, android, button, static, textview

Here is my activity. I am stuck in activity and need help please.
I need to read data, have them as key and result in a map<>. get keys from user by press button show the result of the key and then another button to add them to the list if user approve it.

```
public class ExcelReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "/home/saeid/Documents/ABBREV.xlsx";
public static final Map<String, String> numberDescMap = new HashMap<>();

public final TextView productInput = findViewById(R.id.textView_InputProductNumber);
public final TextView productName = findViewById(R.id.textView_ProductName);
public final Button checkInput = findViewById(R.id.button_GO);
public final Button addInput = findViewById(R.id.button_AddProduct);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reader_excel);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

    // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
    System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

    // obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
    System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
    }

    // Getting the Sheet at index zero
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row rowCount = sheet.getRow(0);
    int totalNumberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int totalNumberOfColumns = rowCount.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    System.out.print("number of rows => " + totalNumberOfRows + "\n");
    System.out.print("number of columns => " + totalNumberOfColumns + "\n");

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    // obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

    for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow < totalNumberOfRows; currentRow++){
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        row = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
        Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
        Cell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
        String cellValue0 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell0);
        String cellValue1 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell1);
        numberDescMap.put(cellValue0,cellValue1);
        //System.out.print(currentRow + "-  *" + dbNumbers + "*" +  "*" + description + "*" + "\n");
    }

    List<String> dbNumbers = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.keySet());
    List<String> description = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.values());

    int checkIndex = 1;
    for (String mapkeys : dbNumbers){
        System.out.println(checkIndex++ + "- " + mapkeys + "==>" +numberDescMap.get(mapkeys) + "\n");
    }

    // Closing the workbook
    workbook.close();
}
}
```

I need to access Buttons and TextViews after main(). I tried several ways but not succeeded so far.
I need to work with Buttons and TextViews after the result in main. I need the map<> before using them. 
I tried make them static as well or define in onCreate() but was not successful. I appreciate any help.

I did this edit after the answer I got
this is the Java file for act as a method

```
public class FileReader{
private final Activity activity;
public FileReader(Activity activity) {this.activity = activity;
}
public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "/home/saeid/Documents/ABBREV.xlsx";
public static final Map<String, String> numberDescMap = new HashMap<>();
public Map<String, String> ExcelFileReader() {
    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
    System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        //System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
    }
    // Getting the Sheet at index zero
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row rowCount = sheet.getRow(0);
    int totalNumberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int totalNumberOfColumns = rowCount.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    System.out.println("number of rows => " + totalNumberOfRows );
    System.out.println("number of columns => " + totalNumberOfColumns );

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    // 1. You can obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow < totalNumberOfRows; currentRow++) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        row = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
        Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
        Cell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
        String cellValue0 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell0);
        String cellValue1 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell1);
        numberDescMap.put(cellValue0, cellValue1);
        //System.out.print(currentRow + "-  *" + dbNumbers + "*" +  "*" + description + "*" + "\n");
    }
    // Closing the workbook
    try {
        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numberDescMap;
}
```

}

I did a debug , the workbook is always null and I get null in activity.

and this is how I call it in activity

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(this);
final Map<String, String> numberDescMap = fileReader.ExcelFileReader();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you understand the activity lifecycle properly. Checkout this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

You don't need to use **public static void main**

```
    public class ExcelReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "/home/saeid/Documents/ABBREV.xlsx";
    public static final Map<String, String> numberDescMap = new HashMap<>();

    public final TextView productInput ;
    public final TextView productName;
    public final Button checkInput ;
    public final Button addInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reader_excel);
        productInput = findViewById(R.id.textView_InputProductNumber);
        productName = findViewById(R.id.textView_ProductName);
        checkInput = findViewById(R.id.button_GO);
        addInput = findViewById(R.id.button_AddProduct);
        createWorkbook();
    }


    createWorkbook(){

        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

        // obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
        System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }

        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row rowCount = sheet.getRow(0);
        int totalNumberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int totalNumberOfColumns = rowCount.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        System.out.print("number of rows => " + totalNumberOfRows + "\n");
        System.out.print("number of columns => " + totalNumberOfColumns + "\n");

        // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        // obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

        for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow < totalNumberOfRows; currentRow++){
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            row = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
            Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
            Cell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
            String cellValue0 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell0);
            String cellValue1 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell1);
            numberDescMap.put(cellValue0,cellValue1);
            //System.out.print(currentRow + "-  *" + dbNumbers + "*" +  "*" + description + "*" + "\n");
        }

        List<String> dbNumbers = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.keySet());
        List<String> description = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.values());

        int checkIndex = 1;
        for (String mapkeys : dbNumbers){
            System.out.println(checkIndex++ + "- " + mapkeys + "==>" +numberDescMap.get(mapkeys) + "\n");
        }

        // Closing the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

You can use all the views instance inside **createWorkbook** method

Comment: thank you for reply and for the link.it did not accept the **creatWorkbook()** method. instead I have this now **ExcelReaderActivity() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{}** which seems to work so far. I am working on it and do not know that is it work or not.

Comment: You don't need to create an activity for doing any utility work. Activity is something which has UI . Each activity is a screen itself. What you can do is create a separate java class ExcelReader.java and initialize it in onCreate and use it

Comment: great, that is a good advice. I am newbie. thank you. can I know please how can I initialize it in onCreate() ?

Comment: ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader();
excelReader.createWorkBook()

Comment: i did the changes and added to question based on your answer, would you please tell me what is the problem now

Comment: why did you need activity in FileReader.java ?

Comment: first lines?
I can remove them but debug showed me that workbook wont initialize

Comment: I think the issue with FileReader method. Just use Logcat and check the logs https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: I checked , still workbook initialization , it is null.
i get java.lang.NullPointerException based on it because it wants to iterate over null object refrence

Comment: I cannot help in each step of debugging. Use Logcat and try to find the issue and learn debugging in android. You can add Log.d in every line of code and check where the issue is. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Do like this 
public class ExcelReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "/home/saeid/Documents/ABBREV.xlsx";
public static final Map<String, String> numberDescMap = new HashMap<>();

private  TextView productInput, productName ;
private Button checkInput , addInput ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reader_excel);
 productName = findViewById(R.id.textView_ProductName);
 productInput = findViewById(R.id.textView_InputProductNumber);
 checkInput = findViewById(R.id.button_GO);
  addInput = findViewById(R.id.button_AddProduct);
 workBookCalculation(); 
}

public void workBookCalculation() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

    // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
    System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

    // obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
    System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
    }

    // Getting the Sheet at index zero
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row rowCount = sheet.getRow(0);
    int totalNumberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int totalNumberOfColumns = rowCount.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    System.out.print("number of rows => " + totalNumberOfRows + "\n");
    System.out.print("number of columns => " + totalNumberOfColumns + "\n");

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    // obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

    for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow < totalNumberOfRows; currentRow++){
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        row = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
        Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0);
        Cell cell1 = row.getCell(1);
        String cellValue0 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell0);
        String cellValue1 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell1);
        numberDescMap.put(cellValue0,cellValue1);
        //System.out.print(currentRow + "-  *" + dbNumbers + "*" +  "*" + description + "*" + "\n");
    }

    List<String> dbNumbers = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.keySet());
    List<String> description = new ArrayList(numberDescMap.values());

    int checkIndex = 1;
    for (String mapkeys : dbNumbers){
        System.out.println(checkIndex++ + "- " + mapkeys + "==>" +numberDescMap.get(mapkeys) + "\n");
    }

    // Closing the workbook
    workbook.close();
}
}
```

And use textview any where in the activity;